# Which Chrome extension can add a `theme-dark` class to the body HTML?

Tags: chrome, dark-theme

I [read](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1492/6753):

> We don't officially support dark mode on SE sites as there are still some accessibility and other issues to iron out, but I went ahead and did a dark mode version of your theme. If you add the `theme-dark` class to the body HTML, you will see this. I believe there are some browser extensions out there that might help with this.

Which Chrome extension can add a `theme-dark` class to the body HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find an extension which does this exactly. However you can do this indirectly with [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).

With this extension you can install scripts created by others (such as the scripts created on https://stackapps.com/), or create your own script. In this case, the code to accomplish this is a very simple one liner:

```
// Adds the `theme-dark` class to the body element if it doesn't already exist
document.body.classList.add("theme-dark");
```

To use this script for SE, first install Tampermonkey, then open the Tampermonkey dropdown and click "Create a new script...", then paste the following code into the editor, then go "File" and click "Save". This looks like a lot more code than I indicated above, but a lot of it is the boilerplate code and metadata that Tampermonkey automatically adds plus some `match` tags so our code only targets Stack Exchange sites.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        https://*.meta.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        https://superuser.com/*
// @match        https://askubuntu.com/*
// @match        https://serverfault.com/*
// @match        https://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match        https://stackapps.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=tampermonkey.net
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    // Adds the `theme-dark` class to the body element if it doesn't already exist
    document.body.classList.add("theme-dark");
})();
```

By the way, I tried using this for a couple sites on the network and a couple don't play well with it (such as English.SE).